# Edge and IE11 XSLT space issue

Tags: javascript, html, xslt, internet-explorer-11, microsoft-edge

I have ran into an issue with Edge and IE11 using XSLT to convert from HTML to XML.
When converting, elements that contain only spaces (one or many) get turned into an empty or self closing element after transform in Edge and IE11 only; Chrome and Firefox persist the spaces. This is true going from XML to HTML and HTML to XML
I have created a Codepen example of the issue ging from HTML to XML which is an ultra chopped down version of the code to demonstrate with minimal noise what the process I am using is.
https://codepen.io/akealey/pen/YzyEmpz

Run the pen in Chrome and Edge and the result will demonstrate Edge removing the space.
Is there any way to preserve the space(s)? I have gone through all sorts of different attributes and settings to do so but nothing works.
The markup being transformed exists on a webpage (the webpage I have full control over, the document I do not).

```js
var outStr, processor, implementationObject, transformedDocument;
// a trimmed down document all the way to the element in question
var xmlStr = '<div> </div>';
// an alternate bare bones xslt. also does not generate a space in the output
var xsltStr = '<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">\n<xsl:output method="xml" encoding="utf-8" indent="no"/>\n<xsl:template match="/">\n<xsl:copy-of select="*" />\n</xsl:template></xsl:stylesheet>';

// create the dom parser
var domParser = new DOMParser();
// parse both xml and xslt into actual dom objects. Note xml has the xml header prepended
var xmlDoc = domParser.parseFromString('<?xml version="1.0" ?>' + xmlStr, 'text/xml');
var xsltDoc = domParser.parseFromString(xsltStr, 'text/xml');

// test what xslt processors are available. if chrome, firefox, edge - else ie11
if (typeof XSLTProcessor !== "undefined" && XSLTProcessor !== null) {
  // Chrome
  // Edge
  // Firefox
  processor = new XSLTProcessor();
  processor.importStylesheet(xsltDoc);
  //edge has the space inside xmlDoc up to this point
  transformedDocument = processor.transformToFragment(xmlDoc, document);
  // inspecting the tansformed document in Edge shows the element has no space but chrome and firefox does
} else if ('transformNode' in xmlDoc) {
  // IE11
  transformedDocument = xmlDoc.transformNode(xsltDoc);
} else {
  console.log('no transform engine found');
}

// turn the converted xml document into a string
var xmlSerializer = new XMLSerializer();
var transformResult = xmlSerializer.serializeToString(transformedDocument);
console.log(transformResult);
// In Edge .serializeToString() turns the element in to a self closing tag (as there is no content)

var hasSpace = /> <\//.test(transformResult);
console.log(hasSpace);
```

Comment: Does it work better with IE or Edge if you use `xsl:output method="html"`? After all inserting XSLT results generated with transformToFragment into an HTML DOM only make sense with that output method.

Comment: @mplungjan Unfortunately not. The output remains exactly the same.

Comment: For pure IE based scripting I think I remember that MSXML has a `preserveWhitespace` property on its DOMDocument that is false by default so for IE you should be able to fix the problem by ensuring you set that property to true before using `load` or `loadXML`. I am not sure how to coach Edge into assuming that or setting that. Are you able to fix the XML input with e.g. `<div xml:space="preserve"> </div>` before parsing?

Answer (score 0):

For IE using MSXML directly I think you need to set `preserveWhiteSpace` to `true` on any DOMDocument before using `load` or `loadXML`, as the default of that property is false (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/desktop/ms761353(v%3Dvs.85)).

For Edge it might help to set up `<div xml:space="preserve"> </div>`.

Comment: This does indeed preserve the space for Edge (i'll get to IE11 tomorrow).
However I cant add 'xml:space="preserve"' to every element in my document (they are vast and I have no control over the imported documents though I do over the containing page itself). In addition the element must not be present in the final document (though that can probably be removed during transform).
Is there any way to apply xml:space="preserve" to an element and everything below?

Comment: If you apply the attribute on the root element or any container element it applies to all descendants as well, unless overriden further down the tree.

Answer (score 0):

Your codepen has errors in IE. `transformNode` is undefined in IE. You need to use `new ActiveXObject('Msxml2.DOMDocument.6.0')` and `loadXML` in IE instead of `DOMParser` to parse XML. For Edge, I'm in favor of Martin's answer: Apply `xml:space="preserve"` on the root element then it will apply to all descendants as well.

The final code sample is like this which can work well in IE and Edge (pay attention to the `//IE11` parts in the code):

```js
function textOrConsole(text, elementSelector) {
  var processorElement = document.querySelector(elementSelector);
  if (processorElement)
    processorElement.innerText = text;
  else
    console.log(text);
}

var outStr, processor, implementationObject, transformedDocument, transformResult;
// a trimmed down document all the way to the element in question
var xmlStr = '<div xml:space="preserve"><div> </div></div>';
// an alternate bare bones xslt. also does not generate a space in the output
var xsltStr = '<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">\n<xsl:output method="xml" encoding="utf-8" indent="no"/>\n<xsl:template match="/">\n<xsl:copy-of select="*" />\n</xsl:template></xsl:stylesheet>';

// create the dom parser
var domParser = new DOMParser();
// parse both xml and xslt into actual dom objects. Note xml has the xml header prepended
var xmlDoc = domParser.parseFromString('<?xml version="1.0" ?>' + xmlStr, 'text/xml');
var xsltDoc = domParser.parseFromString(xsltStr, 'text/xml');

// test what xslt processors are available. if chrome, firefox, edge - else ie11
if (typeof XSLTProcessor !== "undefined" && XSLTProcessor !== null) {
  // Chrome
  // Edge
  // Firefox
  textOrConsole('XSLTProcessor (transformToFragment)', '#transform');
  processor = new XSLTProcessor();
  processor.importStylesheet(xsltDoc);
  //edge has the space inside xmlDoc up to this point
  transformedDocument = processor.transformToFragment(xmlDoc, document);
  // inspecting the tansformed document in Edge shows the element has no space but chrome and firefox does
} else if (!!window.ActiveXObject || "ActiveXObject" in window) {
  // IE11
  var docxml = new ActiveXObject('Msxml2.DOMDocument.6.0');
  docxml.loadXML(xmlStr);

  var docxsl = new ActiveXObject('Msxml2.DOMDocument.6.0');
  docxsl.loadXML(xsltStr);

  transformedDocument = docxml.transformNode(docxsl);
  textOrConsole('xmlDoc.transformNode', '#transform');
} else {
  console.log('no transform engine found');
}

// turn the converted xml document into a string
var xmlSerializer = new XMLSerializer();
if (!!window.ActiveXObject || "ActiveXObject" in window) {
  // IE11
  transformResult = transformedDocument;
} else {
  transformResult = xmlSerializer.serializeToString(transformedDocument);
}
// In Edge .serializeToString() turns the element int oa self closing tag (as there is no content)

var hasSpace = /> <\//.test(transformResult);
textOrConsole("Transformed element: " + transformResult, '#text');
textOrConsole("Has space: " + hasSpace, '#hasSpace');
```

```html
<h3>Result</h3>
<span>Transform used: </span><span id="transform"></span>
<div id="text"></div>
<div id="hasSpace"></div>
</body>
```